Instrument classification on a full audio stem with Yamnet fine-tuned with NSynth dataset
My goal is to feed my model an audio track, or more specifically a stem, and have it predict the instrument of this audio file.
I have done feature extraction on the Yamnet model, trained it with the NSynth dataset, and got it to 90% val accuracy.
The problem that I am having is that my model seems good at predicting the instrument of small samples (e.g. 4-second samples of a single note) and awful at predicting the instrument of a full-size stem (e.g. 3-4 minute audio file). I suspect this is because all of the NSynth dataset is based on individual notes.
So if I want to make predictions on full-size audio files, do I need to find another dataset of stems rather than notes? Or should I somehow try to isolate notes in my current stems (this seems like a rabbit hole I shouldn't go into lol)?
Thanks!
